# Angular Js orderBy with input values

Tags: angularjs

I'm having issues with the orderBy filter.  The following code will order my initiative column just fine.  When I type a value into the input, the filter automatically begins ordering the values just as I want it to.

However, if I type a value into the input that raises that character higher in the list the input will close out before I can finish typing that value.

If the value I type into the input drops the character lower down the list then that input does not close and allows me to finish typing my value.

Can anyone explain this behavior?

```
<tr ng-repeat="char in localChars | orderBy: '-initiative'">
    <td>{{char.name}}</td>
    <td ng-hide='show' ng-click='show = true'>{{char.initiative}}</td>
    <td ng-show='show'>
        <input ng-blur='initiative(char)' ng-model='char.initiative' type="text">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What does "the input will close out" mean? Also, naming a method (`initiative`) the same as a property (`initiative`) can end up being confusing in the long run.

Comment: As you can see the input will show/hide according to the value of show.  What I mean by 'close out' is that it hides.

Comment: So your `ng-blur` is firing before you're done typing because the change in the value caused the list to be reordered thereby causing the input to lose focus?

Comment: That seems to make sense.  But why does it fire a blur event without me clicking outside of the input?

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's what's happening. I'll add an answer with the explanation and a way to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I believe is the sequence of events:

1. User types in input changing the value of `char.initiative`.
2. This causes the list to reorder via the `ng-repeat`.
3. The scope of the `ng-repeat` is re-initialized causing the local `show` variable to lose its value (remember, `ng-repeat` has its own scope).

To fix this you'll need to use [`ng-model-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) to control when the model value actually gets updated. You can choose to update on blur or use a debounce. Here is how to update on blur (my recommendation). You can find info on debouncing at the link.

```
<input ng-blur="initiative(char)" 
       ng-model="char.initiative" 
       ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }"
       type="text" />
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick.  I wasn't aware of the ng-model-options directive until now.  Everything works just as I need it to.  Thanks for the help!